# not able to copy data from excel file to another using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I need to copy exact few columns from Source.xlsx file to Destination.xlsx file.
The screenshot shows sample data in Source.xlsx file.

This link gives me the solution I'm looking for :
[How to copy excel columns from one file to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894268/how-to-copy-excel-columns-from-one-file-to-another) [image]

But this line -> `adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();`

it gives error "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information."

Searched the reason for this error and it is bcoz of table does not have primary key.

Please suggest if any solution/modification we can do for existing code to solve this error.

Comment: Add a primary key?

Comment: @ ashleedawg - which part of code.. do i need to add it..

Comment: I couldn't say, since I don't know what you've got.  You'd need to share the problematic section of your code.  See "[ask]" as well as how to create an [mcve].  Also here's a helpful [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.